# Image in Tooltip of a datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, tooltip

I need to have a datagrid column with some image, and for each cell I need to see, in the tooltip, the bigger image. The datagrid is binded on a ObsevarbleCollection of MyOBjects, and MyImage and MyBigImage are poperties of MyObject. With XAML here there is the working code:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" >
                    <Image.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding MyBigImage}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Image.ToolTip>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

But I need to move the code in the c# side. So I've tried this code:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
FrameworkElementFactory factoryImg = new   FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
Binding b1 = new Binding("MyImage");
b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
factoryImg.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, b1);

DataTemplate ttTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StackPanel));
FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new     FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
FrameworkElementFactory imgHolder = new     FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
Binding b2 = new Binding("MyBigImage");
b2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
imgHolder.SetValue(TextBlock.DataContextProperty, this.pieces);
imgHolder.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, b2);
spFactory.AppendChild(imgHolder);

ttTemplate.VisualTree = spFactory;

ToolTip tt = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
tt.ContentTemplate = ttTemplate;
factoryImg.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, tt);

DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factoryImg;
col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
grdDataItems.Columns.Add(col1);
cellTemplate1.Seal();
```

In the datagrid cell of the column I see the correct image from "MyImage", but in the tooltip of the cell I see always the image of the first element of the collection of "MyBigImage".
How can I solve this?

Regards

Comment: Hi @Ivano,

MyBigImage property is a collection type?

Comment: Hi, "MyImage" and "MyBigImage" are properties (type BitmapImage) of my object class MyPiece. The object "pieces" is an obsevablecollection of MyPiece objects."